# RAM Upgrade: Memory not detected

Tags: memory, ddr3

I purchased memory stick off ebay to upgrade the RAM on my workstation. However it does not get detected at all.

The sticker on the chip reads: 8GB 2Rx4 PC3L 12800R (Samsung).
From the seller it has info as: DDR3 PC3-12800 DDR3-1600  REGISTERED • ECC • Dual Rank  240 pin

I also have a PowerEdge T20 with Xeon E3-1225 and even that makes the beeping noise and does not boots.

So I am trying to find out if I got the correct type of the memory and its likely its a faulty product.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Update: I have a HP Z420 Workstation with Xeon E5-1650 and also have a PowerEdge T20 with Xeon E3-1225

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a discrepancy.

'The sticker on the chip reads: 8GB 2Rx4 **PC3L** 12800R (Samsung). From the seller it has info as: DDR3 **PC3**-12800 DDR3-1600 REGISTERED • ECC • Dual Rank 240 pin'

PC3L is a **Low Power Variant** of PC3.
Your system's motherboard may not supply enough power to support PC3 memory, or your PC3L memory sticks don't tolerate higher voltage.

Either way, the eBay seller has given false information. Consider filing a dispute with the seller.

Comment: I believe PC3L will work at higher voltages, but PC3 will not work at lower voltages.  Either way, his memory wont work.

Comment: The seller has indicated in a separate note that it is a low voltage chip so that does not seem to be the conflict. My original chips in this machine are PC3 so if these chips are PC3L they should be able to operate AT PC3 - is there anything I can do in bios that might make it work. Just want to give it enough attempt to make it work before filing a dispute

Comment: @FaisalKhan The modules are not compatible with your system, end of story

Comment: Thanks for stopping by Ramhound but that was not a useful comment. As the previous commentator suggested it’s  a PC3L module which should work on PC3 mode.

Comment: Your PC3L modules do not tolerate PC3-like voltages. If they did, it should had run out-of-the-box, which is a shame because most PC3L modules do tolerate higher voltages.